# Paying Attention to Overlapping in Text Marking when using openLayers ol.style.Style by javascript?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

The vector layer is geojson format by geoserver server. When I use `ol.style.Text` to marking the `volume_ab` filled, the overlapping occured.

```
textRender_ab = feature.get("volume_ab");
textRender_ba = feature.get("volume_ba");

//定义默认显示样式
var defaultStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#8B8B7A',
    width: 5
  }),
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 4,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'black'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'black'
    })

  })
})

var level = feature.get("them_vc");
// console.log(feature.get("them_vc").length);
// console.log(level);
if (!level && !vcLevels[level]) {
  return defaultStyle;
}

for (var key in vcLevels) {
  if (level == key) {
    style_ab = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 4,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'black'
        })
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: vcLevels[level],
        width: vcWideth[level]
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: "12px YaHei",
        text: textRender_ab.toString(),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        }),
        rotation: 0,
        scale: 1,
        offsetX: 10,
        offsetY: 10
      })
    });
    style_ba = new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: "12px YaHei",
        text: textRender_ba.toString(),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        }),
        rotation: 0,
        scale: 1,
        offsetX: -10,
        offsetY: -10
      })
    });
    return [style_ab, style_ba];
```

impression drawing shows：
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the statement `declutter: true`  after each vector layer, it works perfectly.

Comment: declutter boolean <optional>
false 
Declutter images and text. Decluttering is applied to all image and text styles, and the priority is defined by the z-index of the style. Lower z-index means higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a cluster layer and use that to build up a single text string separated by a newline (or a space if you prefer) for labels which would otherwise overlap.  Style the resulting text in the cluster layer, and style only the geometry in the main layer.  The code would look something like this:

```
var layerStyle = function(feature) {

  var defaultStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#8B8B7A',
      width: 5
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 4,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'black'
      })
    })
  });

  var level = feature.get("them_vc");
  if (!level || !vcLevels[level]) {
    return defaultStyle;
  }

  for (var key in vcLevels) {
    if (level == key) {
      var style_ab = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 4,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'black'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'black'
          })
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: vcLevels[level],
          width: vcWideth[level]
        })
      });
      return [style_ab];
    }
  }

}


var clusterStyle = function(cluster) {

  var text_ab = '';
  var text_ba = '';

  cluster.get('features').forEach( function(feature) {
    var level = feature.get("them_vc");
    if (level && vcLevels[level]) {
        text_ab += feature.get("volume_ab").toString() + '\n';
        text_ba += feature.get("volume_ba").toString() + '\n';
    }
  });

  var style_ab = new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: "12px YaHei",
        text: text_ab,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        }),
        rotation: 0,
        scale: 1,
        offsetX: 10,
        offsetY: 10
      })
    });
  var style_ba = new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: "12px YaHei",
        text: text_ba,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        }),
        rotation: 0,
        scale: 1,
        offsetX: -10,
        offsetY: -10
      })
    });
    return [style_ab, style_ba];
}


var mainLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: layerSource,
  style: layerStyle
});

var clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 10,
    source: layerSource,
    geometryFunction: function(feature) {
      switch (feature.getGeometry().getType()) {
        case 'Point':
          return feature.getGeometry();
        case 'LineString':
          return new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinateAt(0.5));
        case 'Polygon':
          return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
        default:
      }
    }
  }),
  style: clusterStyle
});
```

Comment: First， Thank you very much for your attention to my question.But I don't understand what you mean. Maybe this is my faulty ,because  I didn't explain it clearly. In fact, I have a GeoJSON files from Geosever, it's WFS foramt. When I did the calculation, I got a new field( namely volume_ab and volume_ba). Hence,I need to render the value to user. I also try to do like your advice, but it doesn't work. Thank you for your help again. In addition ，I use styleFunction to do it.